# Expected CORS filter to applied to preflight only once and allow and subsequent request to go through Oauth2ProcessingFilter

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have an Angular frontend App that is authenticated with Keycloak and from there i call the Spring Backend Resource server passing the accesss_token for it to verify with keycloak
As it a CORS App for the backend i added @Bean corsConfigurationSource() on WebSecurityConfigAdapter with preference Ordered.HIGHEST PREFERNCE,so as to take precedence to Oauth2ProcessingFiter.Initial OPTION request pass through with response header from CORS filter ,second the actual resource request also through CORS filtr and OAuth2Processfilter is not invoked and hence it is anonynmous user even though the user is in keycloak.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
           .anyRequest()
           .authenticated();
}

 @Bean

  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 
  UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
 }
 }

  @SpringBootApplication
  @EnableResourceServer
  public class VehicleApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(VehicleApplication.class, args);
}
    }

  application.yml

    security:
    oauth2:
    resource:
    user-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/VMS/protocol/openid- 
     connect/userinfo


     pom.xml
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Expected CORS filter to applied to preflight only once and allow and subsequent request to go through Oauth2ProcessingGilter

Answer (score 0):

Solved it ,Removed CORS filter added a proxy.conf.js from Angular so it is app that makes the request and not browser and then Oauth2Processing filter does the work of checking the token with keycloak